# Script to replace a line with another similar

Tags: shell, unix

I am having a directory where a lot of SQL files are having code as below (line 1) . I want to replace all these occurrences with line 2. Can anyone please suggest me how this can be achieved?

Line 1 :

```
utl_file.Putf(g_logfile, '******This is sample log msg:' || '\n');
```

Line 2:

```
  write_log(log_desc=> '****** This is sample log msg:', prc_name=>l_db_name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like that?

```
#!/bin/sh

# loop over all *.sql files
for file in *.sql; do
   sed -i '
      # if pattern match --> replace the rest of line
      /utl_file.Putf(g_logfile,/ {s/ ||.*/, prc_name=>l_db_name);/}

      # if pattern match --> replace head of line 
      s/utl_file.Putf(g_logfile,/write_log(log_desc=>/
   ' "$file"
done
```

Start this script in the directory with your sql-files. All files with suffix *.sql will be processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but ==> s/ ||.*/, prc_name=>l_db_name);/ replaces all occurances of || in my code with prc_name=>l_db_name which is not i am looking for. Now i want to replace **`|| '\n');`**   with **`, prc_name=>l_db_name);`** Tried this but not working

**`s/ || '\n');/, prc_name=>l_db_name);/`**

Comment: and how to make changes in the same file? Here we are saving in a different file, can we make changes in the same file?

Comment: I have revised my script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
fooutl_file.Putf(g_logfile, '******This is sample log msg:' || '\n');bar

$ awk -i inplace '
    BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]="" }
    s=index($0,old) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))
    }
1' \
    "utl_file.Putf(g_logfile, '******This is sample log msg:' || '\n');" \
    "write_log(log_desc=> '****** This is sample log msg:', prc_name=>l_db_name);" \
file

$ cat file
foowrite_log(log_desc=> '****** This is sample log msg:', prc_name=>l_db_name);bar
```

The above uses GNU awk for inplace editing so you can change all your files at once with a single call to awk: `awk 'script' *`. With other awks just write to a tmp file in a loop: `for f in *; do awk 'script' "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f"; done`.